# Manipulate visio chart using VBA/C# Automation

Tags: vba, automation, visio

We have quite a complex Visio diagram with custom styled shapes and relations between them. Unfortunately the data of the shapes changes very often. So we have to edit the diagram manually. Furthermore we're searching for a way to automate this step. We don't want to edit the styles, only the data. I read on MSDN that the model behind Visio is stored in XML and there's also a VBA reference, which looks good.
My concern is that our approach is to time consuming and we end up with the old approach of doing it manually. Has someone done something similar and can give me a tip?

Comment: Hi, yes I have, it's time consuming, but not as bad as you think.  Start recording macro's in Visio, this will help a great deal.  It's how I started to look at it all.

Comment: What do you mean with recording macros? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean recording doing basic tasks in visio and recording them and then inspecting the generated code.  If you don't know how to do things like that, I'd suggest learning recorded macros as your first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache (N)Poi Library provides features I was looking for.
http://poi.apache.org/diagram/